# error sending linkedarray in function

Tags: android

I want make undo/redo on pbitmap/canvas, but i have got problems with sending a linkedarray between drawhandler.java to panel.java ..

errors:
Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

LinkedArray cannot be resolved to a type

public void onDrawAll(LinkedArray  paths, Paint paint); <-----the error is on this line

All my code can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/V2LYZX7r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you wanted to write `LinkedList` instead of `LinkedArray`?
I don't know in the standard java api a such class LinkedArray, or I am missing something, or that class is from a third party library you use.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface OnDrawListener 
{
          public void onDrawShape(Shape shape, Paint paint); // narišeš shape dokončno

          public void onDrawShapeTemp(Shape shape, Paint paint); // narišeš shape, in ga potem ko je narisan, izbrišeš, če shape ni freehand

          public void onDrawAll(LinkedArray<Path>  paths, Paint paint); <-----there is errror 
}
```